# How to prevent clipping when moving through a tunnel?

Tags: android, camera, opengl-es2, clipping

I'm developing for Android using OpenGL ES 2.0.

It's going to be a game where you have to fly through a tunnel without hitting the walls.

However, the tunnel wall gets clipped as the player approaches. This is especially annoying with the rings as they suddenly disappear, causing an uncomfortable flashing effect.

How can I make sure that the tunnel fills the entire screen?

[image: Tunnel Flyer]

Comment: Try adjusting the near clip plane of the camera.

Comment: Try to scale up the whole thing, so the clipped parts lie outside of projection rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

Try [depth clamping](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut05%20Depth%20Clamping.html). There are some drawbacks but it could potentially solve your problem.

Also, see this question for how to define your own rendering frustum:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792952/how-to-ensure-that-a-plane-perfectly-fills-the-viewport-in-opengl-es